# Application crashing on numberOfRowsSection

Tags: objective-c, arrays

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return [array count];   // <--- Crashes here
}
```

I'm not sure why it is crashing considering the array is a simple NSArray.

Comment: Where is array defined? From your example, it's not defined within the scope of the method. Is it an instance variable? try `self.array.count` if it's a property on your class

Comment: -1 and vote to close because you did not list the complete exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Your "array" must not be an NSArray. Can you provide some context for where array is defined? Are you using ARC?

A simple test would be to put the following line before that return statement:

```
NSLog(@"array = %@; array class = %@", array, array.class)
```

Paste the output from that and I can help you further! My guess currently is that array is being deallocated, and there's some other (or garbage) property in that memory. I wouldn't be surprised if you saw that array.class was an NSNumber...

Comment: Now it's crashing on the NSLog line :P The sad thing is it has worked before and I completely forget what I may have changed to screw it up.

Comment: It's class is __NSArrayI

Comment: What are the crash details? I bet it's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Your "array" variable is invalid.

Comment: It's not showing an error, just shows (lldb) and breaks the thread.

Comment: @NOSDuco - Learn how to get the exception info.